# Specify which of multiple citations is preceded by a prefix in BibTex/natbib/BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing, natbib

I'm trying to add a prefix to a particular citation in LaTeX using BibTex/natbib/BibLaTeX in the context of multiple citations.

Here's what I want to appear:

```
Claim made by several authors (citation01, citation02; but see citation03).
```

Here's my attempt in LaTeX:

```
Claim made by several authors \citep[but see][]{citation01,citation02,citation03}.
```

The problem is that it adds the prefix ("but see") before all of the citations, and I don't know how to specify which citation is preceded by the prefix.  Is there a way to specify where the prefix is inserted?

Comment: i think you may have to input this as two separate `\citep` entries, the first containing the two unqualified references, and the second containing the qualified one with the desired option.  granted, that won't list them together in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `biblatex` and its `natbib` compatibility option, you may use `\citep` for "standard" citations in parentheses. For the case specified in your question, you have to resort to `\parencites`. See section 3.7.3 of the `biblatex` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01}.

Claim made by several authors \parencites{A01}{B02}[but see][]{C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `\ciltealt` command which suppresses the parentheses like this:

```
Claim made by several authors (\citealt{citation01}; 
\citealt{citation02}; but see \citealt{citation03}).
```